# Error can't be catched?: NodeJS/Hyperledger

Tags: node.js, error-handling, try-catch, hyperledger

What is the best way to hide an error?

**I want to get rid of this error (to hide it, or even better solve it if someone knows where is the problem):**

```
    2019-12-12T17:43:54.626Z - error: [Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed\n    
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)\n    
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:26)\n    
    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)\n    
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1306:15)\n    
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)\n    
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)\n    
    at /home/hl-root/fabric-samples/fullgear-4node-setup/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1123:18"
Transaction submitted
```

My code looks like:

```
    while {
         try {
            const gateway = new Gateway();
            await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });
            const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
            const contract = network.getContract('chaincode');
            await contract.submitTransaction('createTransaction', 'Transaction3', '1');
            console.log('Transaction submitted');
        }
        catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
                process.exit(1);
            }
    }
```

I get the error but the instruction is made and i get the date (so catch error never work?)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that network.getContract returns a Promise, so what is happening here is that your code is moving passed that line before the Promise resolves, so your try/catch completes before the error is thrown, hence the exception. Try this:

```
while {
     try {
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
        const contract = await network.getContract('chaincode');
        await contract.submitTransaction('createTransaction', 'Transaction3', '1');
        console.log('Transaction submitted');
    }
    catch (error) {
            console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
            process.exit(1);
        }
}
```